# How to insert the date into vim

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, vim, date

In vim you can execute comands with "!". You can combine that with "r" to insert the output into your current buffer.

> :r!date
>   Fri Jul 20 09:39:26 SAST 2012

will insert the date into a file.

Now when I try to do some more interesting stuff like date with different format +%F.
On the command line

> $ date +%F
>   2012-07-20

In vim

> :r!date "+%F"
>   message.to.followup.lstF

Which out puts the name of the file and puts F after it. some how the r!date "+%F" is being expanded in vim and not run on the command line. What do I need to do to run that so it puts the contents in vim.

Maybe vim has a better way to insert dates into files.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344750/how-do-i-insert-current-time-into-a-file-using-vim

Comment: Here is another valid response using <F3>. You will need to modify your `vimrc` to get [any date format you like, automatized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58604/6253165).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Vim has an internal `strftime()` function.  Try this (in insert mode):

```
<C-r>=strftime('%F')<CR>
```

Comment: I am choosing your answer as it the most vim like way to do things.

Comment: And in **normal mode** this is the same (insert date at **current position**): `"=strftime("%F")<CR>P` (Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time)

Answer (score 22):

I kept experimenting till I figured out that vim was expanding the "%" character. So just escape "\%" and every thing works as I expected.

> :r!date "+\%F"
>   2012-07-20

Now I can put dates into files Like I would like to

> :r!date "+\%F" -d "-2 day"
>   2012-07-18

Comment: +1 That you can use with other programs than `date` too, and hence its easier to remember than the internat "strftime"-thing.

Answer (score 13):

Another method, without escaping, using `system()`:

```
system('date +%F')
```

In *INSERT* mode:

```
<C-r>=system('date +%F')<CR>
```

In *NORMAL* mode:

```
:put=system('date +%F')<CR>
```

Comment: <C-r> is very useful, I wish I had spent more time reading the help in vim.

Comment: It's never too late.